# Programmatically computing dual Hopf algebras: state of the art

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, big-picture, hopf-algebras, mathematical-software

Given a graded Hopf algebra of finite type, we know the (graded) linear dual is also a graded Hopf algebra. For instance the dual Hopf algebra to the polynomial algebra on an even degree generator, $R[x]$, is the divided power algebra, $\Gamma[x]$.

I was wondering what (if any) software exists for performing these type of computations. It seems to me this is the sort of thing which would be possible to do by computational methods.